# utorrent downloads restricted to 10 Kb/s

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

have already set up port forwarding on my netgear wnr1000v2 router and tried adjusting obvious settings

torrent speed, even on very well-shared torrents, will start out at a high dl rate when I open the app and then eventually taper back down to 10 K/s maximum

this happens even on well-seeded torrents

what could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Could your ISP be [Traffic Shaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping) bittorrent traffic?

Comment: it looks like things are working ok with transmission -- until I add a very large torrent (several gigs). maybe there's something where a torrent of that size is interacting with the file system?

Comment: Could be, although I don't have a problem here with large files affecting download speeds. Have a poke around in Preferences/Advanced/Disk Cache and see if any chnages there help.